Sending URL from Sanity Studio Schema causes error in Sanity Studio
I am creating a Website that uses Next.js as my framework and Sanity Studio using the SanityPress template. I am trying to create a module that plays a background video from a Video URL that is received by Sanity Studio. When I pass the video url from a Sanity Studio Schema to my Next.js website it causes an error in Sanity Studio.
I tried sanitizing the URL from the module and that works and occupies the video but error the same!
Sanity Studio Error
Schema Module:
import { defineField, defineType } from 'sanity'
import { TfiLayoutCtaCenter } from 'react-icons/tfi'
import { getBlockText } from '../../src/utils'

export default defineType({
    name: 'hero.video',
    title: 'Hero (Video)',
    icon: TfiLayoutCtaCenter,
    type: 'object',
    fields: [
        // other fields
        }),
        defineField({
            name: 'bgVideo', // New field for video background
            type: 'url',
            title: 'Background Video URL',
            description: 'URL of the background video',
            options: {
                hotspot: true,
            },
        }),
    ],
    preview: {
        select: {
            content: 'content',
            media: 'bgVideo',
        },
        prepare: ({ content, media }) => ({
            title: getBlockText(content),
            subtitle: 'Hero (Video)',
            media,
        }),
    },
})


Next.js Module:
// other imports
import { stegaClean } from '@sanity/client/stega'
import Video from 'next-video' // Import the Video component

export default function Hero({
    pretitle,
    content,
    ctas,
    bgImage,
    bgImageMobile,
    bgVideo,
    textAlign = 'center',
    alignItems,
}: Partial<{
    pretitle: string
    content: any
    ctas: Sanity.CTA[]
    bgImage: Sanity.Image
    bgImageMobile: Sanity.Image
    bgVideo: string
    textAlign: React.CSSProperties['textAlign']
    alignItems: React.CSSProperties['alignItems']
}>) {
    const hasImage = !!bgImage?.asset
    const sanitizedUrl = bgVideo ? encodeURI(bgVideo) : '' // Ensure URL is sanitized
    const hasVideo = !!sanitizedUrl // Ensure this is correctly set

    console.log('Video URL:', sanitizedUrl)
    console.log('Has Video:', hasVideo)

    return (
        <section
            className={cn(
                (hasImage || hasVideo) &&
                    'grid overflow-hidden bg-ink text-canvas *:col-span-full *:row-span-full',
            )}
        >
            {/* Background Video */}
            {hasVideo && (
                <Video
                    src={sanitizedUrl} // Provide the sanitized video source URL
                    autoPlay
                    loop
                    muted
                    playsInline
                    className="absolute inset-0 h-full w-full object-cover"
                    onError={(e) => console.error('Video error:', e)}
                />
            )}

            {/* Background Image */}
            {bgImage?.asset && !hasVideo && (
                <picture>
                    <Source image={bgImageMobile} imageWidth={1200} />
                    <Img
                        className="size-full max-h-fold object-cover"
                        image={bgImage}
                        imageWidth={1800}
                        draggable={false}
                    />
                </picture>
            )}

            {content && (
                <div className="section relative z-10 flex w-full flex-col">
                    <div
                        className={cn(
                            'richtext relative isolate max-w-xl [&_:is(h1,h2)]:text-balance',
                            (hasImage || hasVideo) && 'text-shadow',
                            hasImage && css.txt,
                            {
                                'mb-8': stegaClean(alignItems) === 'start',
                                'my-auto': stegaClean(alignItems) === 'center',
                                'mt-auto': stegaClean(alignItems) === 'end',
                            },
                            {
                                'mr-auto': stegaClean(textAlign) === 'left',
                                'mx-auto': stegaClean(textAlign) === 'center',
                                'ml-auto': stegaClean(textAlign) === 'right',
                            },
                        )}
                        style={{ textAlign: stegaClean(textAlign) }}
                    >
                        <Pretitle
                            className={cn((hasImage || hasVideo) && 'text-canvas/70')}
                        >
                            {pretitle}
                        </Pretitle>
                        <PortableText value={content} />
                        <CTAList
                            ctas={ctas}
                            className={cn('!mt-4', {
                                'justify-start': stegaClean(textAlign) === 'left',
                                'justify-center': stegaClean(textAlign) === 'center',
                                'justify-end': stegaClean(textAlign) === 'right',
                            })}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </section>
    )
}



Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: The string contains invalid characters.
Call Stack:
createElement@[native code]
createElement@http://localhost:3333/node_modules/.sanity/vite/deps/chunk-OGXQOTU6.js:11336:55
createInstance@http://localhost:3333/node_modules/.sanity/vite/deps/chunk-OGXQOTU6.js:12172:41
completeWork@http://localhost:3333/node_modules/.sanity/vite/deps/chunk-OGXQOTU6.js:20136:48
completeUnitOfWork@http://localhost:3333/node_modules/.sanity/vite/deps/chunk-OGXQOTU6.js:23077:37....

Welcome to Stackoverflow! It is a good practice to post error messages as text rather than as image. But please don't add further information as comment. Instead, use the Edit button below your question!
